# How to alias a command if the command contains a certain word at the beginning

Tags: bash, function, conda

I need to alias a command started with conda only at the first time.

What I tried is (in the ~/.bashrc)

```
conda() {
  PYTHONPATH=''
  command conda "$@"
}
```

This works for every conda-included command.

But below doesn't work, which conda-included command is executed only once.

```
state=0
conda() {
  if [ state == 0 ]; then
    state=1
    PYTHONPATH=''
    command conda "$@"
  else
    command conda "$@"
  fi
}
```

If I type conda-included command, it reset PYTHONPATH at just the first time. After the first conda-included command, it should execute raw commands.

Comment: @Cyrus I have another trouble with it. I posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542401/how-to-combine-a-function-of-alias-with-conda-initialize-in-bashrc So, if you can help me again, please visite the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
[ state == 0 ]
```

with

```
[ $state == 0 ]
```

or

```
[ $state = 0 ]
```

or

```
[ $state -eq 0 ] # arithmetic test for equal
```

or ...

Comment: ...or `(( state == 0 ))` or `[[ $state == 0 ]]` or `state=false; if "$state"; then state=true` or ...

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thank you. I forgot to call a variable with $

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I have another trouble with it. I posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542401/how-to-combine-a-function-of-alias-with-conda-initialize-in-bashrc So, if you can help me again, please visite the site.