# How to combine a function of alias with conda initialize in .bashrc

Tags: bash, function, anaconda, alias, conda

I need to combine two different parts in .bashrc
My purpose is to initialize PYTHONPATH as empty before try to initialize conda.

In .bashrc, there is conda initialize part.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/me/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  eval "$__conda_setup"
else
  if [ -f "/home/me/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
    . "/home/me/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
  else
    export PATH="/home/me/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
  fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

But, I have trouble with default PYTHONPATH because I couldn't touch this default except when I want to use conda. So, I create conda() alias. But it comes into conflict with using conda initialize part.

An error message is showed like below.

`CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.`

This means conda initialize was not executed.

Here is conda().

```
state=true
conda() {
  if $state; then
    state=false
    PYTHONPATH=''
    command conda "$@"
  else
    command conda "$@"
  fi
}
```

The .basrh should behavior like once I try to use conda statement on the command line, clearing PYTHONPATH only for the first time before conda initialize works. PYTHONPATH should be untouchable if I'm not trying to use conda statement.

Comment: `conda` is already a bash function (check `declare -f conda`), so you're writing over it and therefore it's not defined when your new function attempts to call it.

Comment: @merv But, after declaring __conda_setup, echo $? shows me 127 status. And conda activate doesn't work if I haven't made PYTHONPATH be an empty value. Alternately, if I get True or False statement whether word conda is in the executed command, I can solve this problem.

Comment: @merv I need to fix the above comment. echo $? displays 0 status at the beginning of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow what's going on or what you're trying to do, but this is something for you to try:

```bash
savePYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=''

# the conda initialize section should go here

PYTHONPATH=$savePYTHONPATH
```

Then you can use your `conda` function.

If this doesn't work, then it still should provide you with some ideas on how to proceed.

Note that once your `conda` function is run, `PYTHONPATH` will stay null even after `state` is `false` unless something else sets it to a non-null value. So I'm not really sure what the conditional is intended to do.

Comment: The declaration of PYTHONPATH was at the end of .bashrc. So, I moved the whole your logic below the declaration line. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Probably, savePYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH is correct on your scheme.